# Trying to understand Eclipse's generated equals method

Tags: java, eclipse, equals

This is the code generated by Eclipse:

`id` is a `String`

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

What looks fishy to me are these line:

```
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
```

Can someone explain to me what it does? I think what it does is check if id of this object is null and if id of the other object is null then the method returns true?

That seems a little strange to me?

Comment: And how does this sound strange? If you don't want that, modify the method so that it suits your need (maybe `id` is never null?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole part after the `.getClass()` test can be rewritten as:

```
return id == null ? other.id == null : id.equals(other.id);
```

That is to say, Eclipse's default `.equals()` will generate code so that if an instance field can be null, it considers equality (for this field at least) true if the other instance's field is also null; otherwise it compares the values.

(note that in the case where `id` is not null but `other.id` is, this will still work, since the `.equals()` contract stipulates that for any object `o`, `o.equals(null)` is false)

Now, it may, or may not, suit your needs; but what Eclipse does here seems logical to me.

Except that it generates code which is way too long ;)

Note that it requires that the `id` field obeys the `.equals()` contract!

Also, if you use Java 7, the code is even shorter:

```
return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

*As per eclipse*, if there are 2 `Person` objects with `id == null`, then they are ***equal***. You can remove it if it doesn't work in your context

You can replace it with below code, to avoid the same

```
if (id == null || other.id == null) {
       return false;
}
```

Comment: You can't just barge in and do whatever you want in `equals`. Can you prove this satisfies the properties of *symmetry*, *reflexivity*, and *transitivity*? Hint: it *doesn't*.

Comment: In your case (id == null || other.id == null) how can we invoke the equals method if this object is null? It may throw null pointer exception?

Comment: @Sripathi `this` will never be `null` on an invoked method. Do you see any mention of `this == null` here?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree with eclipse/you. Everyone may not.. its upto them to define equality on the context of their object definition.. I just explained what it means, and how it can be avoided

Comment: @sanbhat There is no freedom of choice here. Read the javadoc of `equals`. It is dangerously wrong to recommend, even implicitly, writing `equals` which breaks its basic contract.

Comment: I thought @sanbhat answer was pretty reasonable to me. What is wrong with his answer?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : So the Id of the this object can be null?

Comment: @PeterWarbo Which part of my argumentation do you find questionable?

Comment: @Sripathi Yes, any reference-typed variable *may* generally be `null`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I haven't clearly understood your arguments (I'm a junior developer myself). But sanbhat's answer seems reasonable to me that's all. I mean if either `id` of `this` or `other` object is null then the objects are not equal (at least in my context).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: My doubt is if the this object's id is null the this object should be null. In that case can we invoke the equals method of this object that is null.

Comment: @PeterWarbo Does that mean that an object with a null ID is not equal to itself?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yep that's what it means, so I agreee that is a little strange though. Maybe I'll just keep that condition then to satisfy the properties of symmetry, reflexivity, and transitivity. Though it's a condition that should never occur.

Comment: @PeterWarbo If ID should never be null, then the creation of such object should be prevented in the first place. If you must add ID after creation, then an explicit validation step should be in place after the object is deemed "initialized" and before any comparison with other objects is involved.

Comment: @PeterWarbo However, if you start your `equals` with `if (this == o) return true;` and follow that with the logic under discussion here, then I believe you are in the clear. So that's my suggestion on how to improve this answer: making this point explicit.

Comment: Another point: if you touch `equals`, you'd better make sure you update `hashCode` to match the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns true if the `id` of the two objecs has the same value or the two are null.

```
if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
```

this code check if the `id` of this object is null and if the `id` of the other object is diferent of null return false

```
} else if (!id.equals(other.id))
     return false;
```

in the else as we know that id is diferent from null we can call the method equals of id and return false if the two `id` are not equal

If non of this conditions are meet, a true will be return.